# "Add Documentation" is disabled in Xcode 9.1 (9B55)

Tags: xcode

For example:

[image: Add Documentation Disabled]

Any ideas?

MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1
Xcode 9.1 9B55

Comment: I have the same configuration (macOS and Xcode versions) and it works fine. https://i.imgur.com/JA9Pkxq.png. I'd suggest quitting Xcode, emptying derived data folder, restarting Xcode and trying again. Failing that, rebooting. Or try this in a new, blank project and seeing if the problem is unique to your project or something broader.

Comment: Tried all that, in that order, but unfortunately, no luck on my side. :-( Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

As [KellyTheDude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413651/kellythedude) mentioned, renaming or moving the Xcode.app will fix the issue on OSX 10.13 (High Sierra) since /usr/libexec/xpccachectl (the preferred solution) does not seem to exist under this version of the OS.   To fix quickly:

1. Rename Xcode in the applications folder temporarily.
2. Name it back to Xcode

**UPDATE:** This fix also works on macOS Mojave (10.14) and Xcode 10

**UPDATE:** This also fixes the Xcode Source Editor not showing up in System Preferences under Extensions (for Swiftify, etc.)

Comment: With luck we won't see the core issue on Xcode 10.  If anyone does see it, let us know.

Comment: I have the same error (again) under XCode 10. moving or renaming doesn't help. next try is reinstall xcode.

Comment: I just had it happen in Xcode 10 again (in Objective C) and the renaming trick did still work.

Comment: Same for me, Trick works in Xcode 10. I guess this is happening if the Beta version was installed and removed

Comment: Not working for me. After renaming, I can not open Xcode at all. I have resigned Xcode for some old plugins, will it affects this?

Comment: I'm floored that this worked. This is the oddest bug I've ever seen.

Comment: Big thanks to you, still worked in xCode 10.1 (10B61).

Comment: One of the most bizarre solutions. Works for me on Mojave (10.14.2 (18C54)) Objective C framework, Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: Whoa, black magic! I know "thank you" comments are forbidden, but there's literally no way I would have ever figured this out... The problem happened to me in release version of Xcode 10.2, Mojave 10.14.4; this fix worked.

Comment: A bit more detail for what worked for me: Quit Xcode, rename in finder to "Xcode foo.app", immediately rename back to "Xcode.app", no need to relaunch Xcode in between renames

Comment: Still works on 10.2.1. Just quit Xcode, rename to anything (Xcode.app___) then back Xcode.app, then relaunch. Crazy how this works, anyone has an explanation?

Comment: Can't imagine how desperate someone has to be to try renaming the app but amazing trick!

Comment: Also works for the "Xcode source editor not showing in System Preferences Extensions panel" issue on macOS 10.15.6 and Xcode 11.6 (adding to help future searchers. Took a while to find this post).

Comment: Thanks Apple for a crap development environment. Did I mention I hate XCode?

Comment: This issue was fixed quite a while ago I'm pretty sure. Hopefully you can update to a newer Xcode version

Answer (score 5):

Oddly I was able to fix this by moving my Xcode.app to Applications. I originally had it nested in a subdirectory under there to version it, but alas, someone must have hardcoded a path somewhere.

Comment: For me neither of the other solutions worked, only this: moved out Xcode from Applications folder then put it back.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by quitting Xcode and deleting all the files in directory `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me once in awhile and deleting derived data and restarting Xcode doesn't work for me. I usually have to do the following:

1. Close Xcode
2. Execute command in terminal: `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl`
3. Restart my computer.

**Restarting the computer is a required step.**

Source: [Apple Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53339)

Comment: On my machine that isn't even a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Xcode10.1.
All Answers here did not work for me.
I was able to solve this issue only by reinstalling Xcode.

1. Delete Xcode10.1 and empty trash.
2. Delete all files in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` directory and empty trash.
3. Restart Mac.
4. Download and install Xcode10.1.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:**

Xcode > Preferences > Key bindinds > Now Search for "Documentation" in search bar you will see key for *Add Documentation*

**Step 2:**

Double click and assign new key as **"Alt + Control + /"**

**Result:** It will work now but if you want to change it back to what it was **(Alt + command + /)** you can do that.

Also, this will enable the Add Documentation in Editor > Structure

Its a hack and worked for me.